# CakePhp 2.x HABTM SaveAll

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying for 3 days to make it work, already apply all i have seen on stack/forums/google.
A subscribers habtm subrcriberlist and a subscriberslist can belongs to many subscribers.

```
/* Subscriber model*/
     public $hasAndBelongsToMany =
array(
    'Subscriberslists' => array(
        'className' => 'Subscriberslist',
        'joinTable' => 'subscribers_subscriberslists',
        'foreignKey' => 'subscriber_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'subscriberslist_id',
        'unique' => true
    )
);
/* Subscriberslist model*/
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany =
array(
    'Subscribers' => array(
        'className' => 'Subscriber',
        'joinTable' => 'subscribers_subscriberslists',
        'foreignKey' => 'subscriberslist_id', 
        'associationForeignKey' => 'subscriber_id',
        'unique' => true
    )
);
```

Datas are formatted like indicated in all post i have seen :

```
array(
'Subscriberslist' => '1',
'Subscriber' => array(
    'Subscriber' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3'
    )
)
```

Then i could not save my data in my join table. Cake only save new Subscribers. Here is my controller :

```
if (!$this->Subscriber->saveAll($this->request->data){ //error}else{//no error}
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you're trying to insert a subscriber, the `saveAll` method is expecting something like the following:

```
array(
    'Subscriber' => array(/* Single subscriber fields here */),
    'Subscriberslist' => array(
        /* List subscribers here */
    )
)
```

Try using the `saveAssociated` method first because that is expecting a single instance of the model you're trying to save but will persist the associated data with it. If you need to save multiple subscribers at once then change up a gear and revert to `saveAll`:

```
array(
    array(
        'Subscriber' => array(/* Single subscriber fields here */),
        'Subscriberslist' => array(
            /* List subscribers here */
        )
    ),
    array(
        'Subscriber' => array(/* Single subscriber fields here */),
        'Subscriberslist' => array(
            /* List subscribers here */
        )
    )
)
```

I hope this was of some help!